# Can't create a 3 column UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, autolayout

I am trying to create a 3 column UICollectionView/grid view but despite everything I tried I have not been successful.

The code I used is below:

```
import UIKit

class SearchResultsViewController: UIViewController,UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

// Actual code
@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
public var results: [UIImage]!

func loadImages(images: [UIImage]) {
    results = images
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    collectionView.dataSource = self
    collectionView.delegate = self

    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)

    // Disable the margins
    let flow = collectionView?.collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout
    collectionView.contentOffset = CGPoint.zero
    flow.estimatedItemSize = UICollectionViewFlowLayout.automaticSize
    flow.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
    flow.minimumLineSpacing = 0
}

// UICollectionView
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 64
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    let screenWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
    return CGSize(width: screenWidth/3, height: screenWidth/3)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
    return UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 5, right: 5)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)


    return cell
}
```

}

I am looking for a three column layout simmilar to photo apps like Instagram use (note the 64 is there as dummy data so I can test that it works, if this works it will be replaced with actual images)

Instead of getting the expected result, I end up with this:
[[image: Unexpected result1]]

Comment: Why are you adding a right inset of 5? Every additional space you add has to be removed from your item width calculation, in your case (screenWidth - 5) / 3.

Answer (score 0):

Use like this:

```
lazy var collectionView: UICollectionView = {
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.scrollDirection = .vertical
    layout.minimumLineSpacing = 10
    layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 10
    let width = (view.frame.width - 10 * 3) / 2
    layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: width, height: width)
    layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 10, bottom: 10, right: 10)
    let cv = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    cv.delegate = self
    cv.dataSource = self
    cv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    cv.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
    cv.backgroundColor = .clear
    return cv
}()
```

Also, you don't need to use these methods. No more required.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
}
```

[image: Output Screenshot]